# How to escape single quote with MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

With a Spring Boot project, I use an import.sql file to initialize a database.
Today, I don't have any problem, and it works properly.
This is an extract of the original file :

```
insert into ref_building (code, label, description) values ("METAL", "Métal", "Permet d'extraire");
insert into ref_building (code, label, description) values ("PETROLE", "Pétrole", "Permet d'extraire");
```

To improve the readability of the SQL file, I decide to use *MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor* in the YAML properties, like this :

```
spring:
   jpa :
     properties:
      hibernate:
        connection:
          charSet: UTF-8
        hbm2ddl:
          import_files_sql_extractor: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
```

After I add this, I have an error with Spring Boot.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "insert into ref_building [...]
```

After analysis, the problem is the single quote ("Permet d'extraire")

So I escape the single quote in this way:

```
insert into ref_building (code, label, description) values ("METAL", "Métal", "Permet d''extraire");
insert into ref_building (code, label, description) values ("PETROLE", "Pétrole", "Permet d''extraire");
```

I don't have error at launch, but in my database I find a value : *Permet d''extraire* (with two single quote)

I don't understand how to escape this correctly (and why it doesn't work specifically with MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor).

Comment: Edit : Doesn't work also with `"Permet d\'extraire"` (first case) and `"Permet d\\'extraire"` (second case)

Comment: when you say it doesnt work with `"Permet d\'extraire"` do you mean it throws an error, or adds the double single quote into the table similar to `"Permet d''extraire"`?

Comment: Yes, it throws also an error for this two cases.

Comment: did you try using single quotes around the entire thing like `'Permet d''extraire'`?

Comment: Great ! That's work in this way, thanks

Comment: So, it's just an interpretation problem for double quote